# Inheritance when defining a class within a class

Tags: python, selenium

Will my class inherit all of the properties of the main class when it's defined within it? My code is:

```
class DashboardPage(BasePage):

    def __ini__(self,driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    class MeetingsPage():

        def createMeeting(self):
            pass

        def editMeeting(self):
            pass

    class EmailsPage():

        def writeEmail(self):
            pass
```

Will the MeetingsPage/EmailPage inherit properties/methods of the BasePage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python the syntax for a derived class definition looks like `DerivedClassName(BaseClassName):` or multiple inheritance `class DerivedClassName(Base1, Base2, Base3):`. As you can see your classes (MeetingsPage/EmailPage) have not been derived from `BasePage`. So they do not inherit any properties and methods from `BasePage`.

Read, please, doc https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

No. You are only restricting the scope. If you want the nested class to inherit from a base class, do so as normal (e.g. `class X(Y):`).

Answer (score 0):

No it will not. A nested class behaves like any "outer" (un-nested) class. It can be instantiated like this.

Ex: obj = DashboardPage().MeetingsPage()

The methods of a nested class may access the instance attributes of the nested class instance but not of any outer class instance.